# Command to create a new project in fortify

Tags: fortify

I want to create a new project in fortify server. Any fortify commands available to create a new project in fortify server? I know we can do it on GUI but i want to write an automated shell script to create new project in fortify server.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Fortify SSC distribution, in the Samples directory can be found a number of Fortify SSC webservices API sample programs.

Unfortunately none of the samples are minimal representations of the WebServices API... but if you look at ProjectProvisioning example, this demonstrates the creation of new ProjectVersions with their Project Attributes.